# request.user returns admin user and not the logged in user

Tags: django

I am building a Django web app with Token Authentication. When I am trying to get username on home page after logging in I get request.user as admin and not the logged in user. Deleted the admin token then too getting the same.
My View is 
`

```
class GalleryView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "galleriesView.html"
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(GalleryView, self).get_context_data()
        print (self.request.user)
        context['user'] = self.request.GET.get('user')
        print (context['user'])
        data = {}
        o = Organisation.objects.filter(org_user=(Account.objects.filter(email=context['user'])))
        for org in range(len(o)):
            g = Gallery.objects.get(organisation=Organisation.objects.filter(name=o[org]))
            data[o[org]] = g
        context['org'] = data.keys()
        context['gallery_results'] = data.values()
        return context`
```

I get admin and None but not the logged in user

Comment: If you get the admin in request.user, the logged user is the admin user. The error is in the authentication not in de view,

Comment: No I checked the token is there for logged in user abc and not admin...I tried to logout the admin and it gives response already logged out